# vkbottle не отвечает на все сообщения

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

vkbottle ни в какую не хочет мне отвечать на сообщения, даже когда копирую шаблон с документации, даже пробовал токен менять. Что не так?

```
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message

bot = Bot("мой токен")

@bot.on.message()
async def any_message(message: Message):
 await message.answer("Hey")

bot.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, проблема в сообществе, которое ты не настроил должным образом. Во первых, вижу, что у тебя используется Long Poll API, используй последнюю стабильную версию **5.103**. После этого, проверь типы событий, которые в этой же вкладке. Если не хочешь заморачиваться, ставь всё, но можешь чуть-чуть почитать и выбрать только то, что ты будешь использовать. После этого всё должно работать.

Так же стоит напомнить, что нужно включить доступ к сообщениям для бота. Это в разделе Сообщения.